# Complex double array into double array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svm

How do I convert a complex double array into double array (numeric matrix) in MATLAB?  I would like to use this as input to a Support Vector Machine.

[image]

Comment: Can you not use a list of complex numbers i.e. List<double[,]>?

Comment: @Jegan This is a MATLAB question, not C#.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is real with some residual complex components.  Simply use the [`real`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) function.

```
texturedata = real(texturedata);
```

Comment: thank you for the help...do you can help me,how to combine all the double array?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You have a single array here.  What combination are you referring to?